# Has Shockwave range been nerfed in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just started playing ME3, and it appears that the cast range for Shockwave is greatly reduced.  've only played the starting mission on Earth, but it seems like I had to wait for the enemies to get much closer to use Shockwave than I did in ME2.  Am I just not doing something right or has the effective range for Shockwave been nerfed?

Comment: Shockwave's range in Mass Effect 3 is 10m, it can be improved to 15m. I'm not sure offhand what its range in ME2 was, perhaps somebody else can chime in.

Comment: shockwave in ME2 was much much longer

Comment: This question just makes me sad.  I've yet to play my Vanguard, but suffice it to say, I would have been spamming shockwave with her.  I found it to be an incredibly useful bunker busting skill.

Comment: @MBraedley Vanguard is still super powerful. YOu just don't get a long range power too now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The people at Bioware wanted to balance out the classes.